# Can't install python modules with pip on Windows Server: access is denied

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, command-prompt

I cannot install any python module anymore on my Windows Server 2012 anymore.
I tried the following commands

```
pip install pypyodbc
python -m pip install pypyodbc
```

but I get these errors:

[image]

I also tried to re-install or repair python and upgrade pip but nothing.
Moreover I access to my server with administrator account and I run command prompt with administrator privileges but I always get this error. I can't even run python.exe application from start menu because I get this:

[image]

Is there a reason for all these errors?
I don't know why these errors start to occur because untile few days ago it all seemed to work fine.

Comment: The error from running Python from the start menu is `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED` (0xC0000142), so the `DllMain` of a DLL failed -- maybe msvcr90.dll or python27.dll. You need to run under a debugger such as WinDbg to figure out the problem, but that's a debugging adventure that may take hours to unravel. Or just uninstall Python; completely remove "C:\Python27" and the registry key(s) `[HKLM | HKCU]\[SOFTWARE | SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node]\Python\PythonCore\2.7`, and reinstall a fresh installation. If there's still a problem try reinstalling the Visual C++ 2008 redistributable.

Comment: In the end I managed to make it work by restarting the server. I waited until 22 pm when I was sure none of our customers was working on the web applications released in it and then I restarted it. it seems everything works fine now.

Comment: It seems like it would have been an interesting failure to debug -- to figure out what problem a reboot solved.